# Accept Privacy Policy Contact Form-7 in two lines

Tags: wordpress, contacts, contact-form, contact-form-7

I have an acceptance button with my contact form 7 plugin, but it is separating the button from the linked text in two different lines. How can I fix this?

```
> <div class="align-center"> [acceptance acceptance-564 ]<a
> href="http://www.jornadasdeldeportelarobla.com/aviso-legal/">Acepto la
> Política de Privacidad</a> </div>
```

That´s the code I am using to create the contact form and this is a picture of how it looks:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mh8Rm.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
.wpcf7 input[type="acceptance"],
.wpcf7-list-item-label {
    display: inline!important;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

I've got same problem. I solved with these:

HTML (Edit Contact Form)

`<div class="acceptance-container"> [acceptance acceptance-443] Acconsento al trattamento dei dati personali D.Lgs. 196/2003 (<a href="#">link</a> di approfondimento) <br /></div>`

then I put in CSS these code

`.wpcf7-form-control-wrap { display: inline!important; }`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4xaU.png)

Comment: Same problem, this doesn't work for me unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked:

```css
.wpcf7 input[name="acceptance-564"] {
    width: 16px;
}
```